# EFI Ubuntu not auto-booting or shown in bios

Tags: boot, server, 20.04

After having installed Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS, when starting my laptop it throws an error stating "No bootable device". When I enter the boot options menu by spamming F12 on startup, I find the "EFI device: Ubuntu" which makes the OS boot. However, when I open the BIOS by spamming F2, in the boot order menu, I can't find it. Any idea how I can make it the default boot drive anyway?

Laptop: Acer Aspire V3-571G

Operating System: Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: Is your UEFI (BIOS) set to boot in Legacy/CSM/BIOS mode only? If so, you need to change it to boot in UEFI mode as your Ubuntu server is installed in UEFI mode.

Comment: @user68186 I can't find any UEFI settings in my BIOS at all. This laptop has never run Windows 8 or 10, so I don't think I even have those options..

Comment: Also, I don't think the Ubuntu Server is UEFI, as in the boot option menu (F12) it's called "EFI device: Ubuntu".

Comment: EFI is uEFI. Do you have latest UEFI from Acer. Many Acer usres have had to upgrade UEFI to set "trust". Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot